# Check for duplicate entries in a large matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, duplicates

I have a very large matrix (901x1801) which I generated by combining values of three similar arrays (with repeated values in them) to generate unique codes using a mathematical expression. The matrix is filled with these codes.

My question is... How can I check that each values of the matrix (901x1801) is unique and not repeating even a single time?

Or...
Can anyone tell me how can I generate a matrix by combining three arrays of similar elements in a way that each generated value will be unique.

an early reply will be greatly appciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you write that your matrix is "filled with these codes", something is not clear, does you array contains numbers or strings (expressions)?

Comment: The matrix I want to check is filled with the codes I generated with 3 different arrays (numbers). I have to use particular data arrays to generate these unique codes. I can't just use random numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a large matrix `M`, to get all the unique values, use:

```
uniqueValues = unique(M(:));
```

Then, to understand if there were any repeated values, you could use:

```
repeatedValuesFound = numel(uniqueValues) ~= numel(M);
```

That is, if the array of unique values has the same number of elements as the original array, then all elements of the original array must be unique.

Comment: You don't need `M(:)`. Unique always returns vector.

Comment: Dear Pusuit, unfortunately I have to use particular data arrays to generate these unique codes. I can't just use random numbers. But, my main problem is to check whether all codes in the matrix (901x1801) are unique and non of them is duplicate of other. Checking such a large array is a problem for me.

Comment: Who is using random numbers?  The `unique` function should work on any numeric matrix or cell array of strings.

Comment: Sorry buddy for not understanding your answer at first place. It worked perfectly. But unfortunately I am not able to figure out how I can build such matrix with no duplicates from my defined arrays. Can you please help me for this as well? It may be because my values are just separated by 0.2. Any idea..

Comment: Sounds like it could be an interesting stackoverflow question.  To make it understandable you need to write up a toy-sized (maybe 4-by-3) example with representative inputs and desired properties of the output.  Right now it is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Array1 = (-180:0.2:180); Array2 = (-90:0.2:90); Num = 100;
I want to make a matrix 'M' by combining all three (Array1, Array2 and Num) in which every single element has to be uniquely identifiable. The size of 'M' will be 1801x901.

Answer (score 4):

To find the positions of duplicates in M, use the following code:

```
V = M(:);                           % flatten
[Vs, Vi] = sort(V);                 % sort, Vi are indices into V
delta = Vs(2:end) - Vs(1:end-1);    % delta==0 means duplicate
dup1 = Vi(find(delta == 0));        % dup1 has indices of duplicates in V
dup2 = Vi(find(delta == 0) + 1);    % dup2 has the corresponding other 
                                    % rewrite to [row col]
[dup1(:,1) dup1(:,2)] = ind2sub(size(M), dup1);
[dup2(:,1) dup2(:,2)] = ind2sub(size(M), dup2);
```

The rows of dup1 and dup2 now contain positions in M that are duplicate.